# Is it possible to run a command from /bin directory of a project from a sub directory?

Tags: bash

I have a c5 project with a directory `C5PROJECTDIR` it has a bin directory. Is there a way (without adding `C5PROJECTDIR/bin` to `$PATH`) to access commands from any other subdirectory of `C5PROJECTDIR`?

For example:
There is an `x` command located here: `C5PROJECTDIR/bin/x`.
I want to run this command from a bash script from `C5PROJECTDIR/packages/some-other-dir`.

UPDATE: The sub directory can be more or less deeper in the tree...

How can it be possible?

Comment: 1/ use an absolute or relative path e.g. ../../bin/x 2/ add …/C5PROJECTDIR/bin to your path

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` variable only make things easier.

You able to run any commands with absolute path like `/bin/echo` or `/home/jon/myscript`. Relative path works as well `~/../../bin/ls`.

Script have its own `PATH` variable, so you can add the desired location to `PATH` in your script if you like.

Apart from this you have to deal with permissions.
The user that have script executed by, must have execute permission on the `x` script.

---

To find and execute command:

```
find C5PROJECTDIR -type f -executable -name "x" -exec {} \;
```

Find's must be strict to match only one command else it will execute all that it fund. You cannot have script with the same name under `C5PROJECTDIR` in this case.

From security point of view. I do not recommend this, as anyone can put an executable file under `C5PROJECTDIR` with a name used in the script. things can go nasty.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is not so trivial becouse the sub directory level can be 1,2 or more so can not use reative path also becouse I do not know the deepness...

Comment: Do want help about find script named `x` under `C5PROJECTDIR` and execute it? your question as it is now, is miss leading in that case. Please clear what you like to achieve here precisely.

Comment: Using find commands seems to be a good solution.
I can find the right directory with "find concrete/bin -type d" from the project dir but how can i use find from a sub directory when the directory to find is a a child of a parent directory, not below my subdirectory. There are also many other c5 directories in upper levels with the same directory....

Comment: If you want only one match, you need something unique to make find command useful, file name, directory name, only that file executable, etc etc. it is very blury how your directory structure looks like,  without seeing it I cannot tell more. It is also unclear why would you execute find from a sub directory while you know the project top directory, but even in that case put `../` at the end of the path in the find command would move up by one directory and look in that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

**Use relative paths:**

Essentially call the binary directly with its path, but relative to the current script. If your script is located in `/home/user/foo/C5PROJECTDIR/packages/somedir/script`, then you call the script relatively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
../../bin/x
```

The problem with this method is maintainability. Imagine you want to move your script to  `/home/user/foo/C5PROJECTDIR/packages/scripts`, then you would have to update all your scripts.

**Use a shell variable:**

Instead of relative paths, you can define a variable `PROJECTHOME` which contains the base value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECTHOME=/home/user/foo/C5PROJECTDIR
$PROJECTHOME/bin/x
```

This generally solves most problems unless you move project location from `/home/user/foo/C5PROJECTDIR` to `/home/user/random-dir`. But this can be solved with a simple `sed` command that searches for the line `/home/user/foo/C5PROJECTDIR` and replaces it.